# Show woocommerce product custom fields under the cart and order item name

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, orders

I have a code that shows custom fields in the "General" tab on the product edit page.

After the manager has filled these fields, the data is displayed on the Archive/Category pages and in the Single Product page.

Also, these fields are in the cart and on the checkout page.

Here is my code:

```
// Display Fields using WooCommerce Action Hook
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_options_general_product_data', 'woocom_general_product_data_custom_field' );

function woocom_general_product_data_custom_field() {
  // Create a custom text field

  // Custom Weight Field
  woocommerce_wp_text_input( 
    array( 
      'id' => '_custom_weight', 
      'label' => __( 'Weight dishes', 'woocommerce' ), 
      'placeholder' => '',
      'desc_tip' => 'true',
      'description' => __( '', 'woocommerce' ) 
    )
  );     

  // Calories Field
  woocommerce_wp_text_input( 
    array( 
      'id' => '_сalories', 
      'label' => __( 'Calories', 'woocommerce' ), 
      'placeholder' => '',
      'desc_tip' => 'false',
      'description' => __( '', 'woocommerce' ) 
    )
  );  

  // Ingredients Field
  woocommerce_wp_textarea_input( 
     array( 
       'id' => '_ingredients', 
       'label' => __( 'Ingredients', 'woocommerce' ), 
       'placeholder' => '',
       'desc_tip' => 'true',
       'description' => __( '', 'woocommerce' ) 
     )
 );
}

// Hook to save the data value from the custom fields
add_action( 'woocommerce_process_product_meta', 'woocom_save_general_proddata_custom_field' );

// Hook callback function to save custom fields information 
function woocom_save_general_proddata_custom_field( $post_id ) {

  // Save Custom Weight Field
  $custom_weight = $_POST['_custom_weight'];
  if( ! empty( $custom_weight ) ) {
     update_post_meta( $post_id, '_custom_weight', esc_attr( $custom_weight ) );
  } else {
     delete_post_meta( $post_id, '_custom_weight' );
  }      

  // Save Calories Field
  $сalories = $_POST['_сalories'];
  if( ! empty( $сalories ) ) {
     update_post_meta( $post_id, '_сalories', esc_attr( $сalories ) );
  } else {
     delete_post_meta( $post_id, '_сalories' );
  }   

  // Save Ingredients Field
  $ingredients = $_POST['_ingredients'];
  if( ! empty( $ingredients ) ) {
     update_post_meta( $post_id, '_ingredients', esc_html( $ingredients ) );
 } else {
     delete_post_meta( $post_id, '_ingredients' );
  }                 

}

// Displaying the custom field value (on single product pages under short description)
add_action('woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_form', 'display_custom_meta_field_value', 25 );
add_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'display_custom_meta_field_value', 25 );
function display_custom_meta_field_value() {
global $product;

$custom_weight = get_post_meta( $product->get_id(),'_custom_weight', true );
if( ! empty( $custom_weight ) )
    echo  '<p id="value-on-single-product">' . 'Weight: ' . $custom_weight . 'g' . '</p>';

$сalories = get_post_meta( $product->get_id(),'_сalories', true );
if( ! empty( $сalories ) )
    echo  '<p id="value-on-single-product">' . 'Calories: ' . $сalories . ' kcal.' . '</p>';

$ingredients = get_post_meta( $product->get_id(),'_ingredients', true );
if( ! empty( $ingredients ) )
    echo '<p id="value-on-single-product">' . 'Ingredients: ' . $ingredients . '</p>';
}


// Render the custom product field in cart and checkout
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_item_data', 'woocom_custom_fields_cart', 10, 2 );
function woocom_custom_fields_cart( $cart_data, $cart_item ) 
{
    $custom_items = array();

if( !empty( $cart_data ) )
    $custom_items = $cart_data;

// Get the product ID
$product_id = $cart_item['product_id'];

if( $custom_field_value = get_post_meta( $product_id, '_custom_weight', true ) )
    $custom_items[] = array(
        'name'      => __( 'Weight', 'woocommerce' ),
        'value'     => $custom_field_value,
        'display'   => $custom_field_value . 'g',
    );

return $custom_items;
}
```

But unfortunately, it’s impossible for me to add these custom fields after the product name on the Thank You page, in the E-mail and on the order editing page.

I also have doubts whether the above code is correct, although everything works.

I will be glad for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have revisited your code and made some changes, adding the necessary code to display your custom fields data on cart, checkout, order received, my account order view and on email notifications *(for Woocommerce 3+)*:

```
// Backend: Display additional product fields
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_options_general_product_data', 'add_fields_to_options_general_product_data' );
function add_fields_to_options_general_product_data() {
    // Custom Weight Field
    woocommerce_wp_text_input( array(
        'id' => '_custom_weight',
        'label' => __( 'Weight dishes', 'woocommerce' ),
    ));

    // Calories Field
    woocommerce_wp_text_input( array(
        'id' => '_сalories',
        'label' => __( 'Calories', 'woocommerce' ),
    ));

    // Ingredients Field
    woocommerce_wp_textarea_input( array(
        'id' => '_ingredients',
        'label' => __( 'Ingredients', 'woocommerce' ),
    ));
}

// Backend: Save the data value from the custom fields
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_process_product_object', 'save_admin_product_custom_fields_values' );
function save_admin_product_custom_fields_values( $product ) {
    // Save Custom Weight Field
    if( isset( $_POST['_custom_weight'] ) ) {
        $product->update_meta_data( '_custom_weight', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['_custom_weight'] ) );
    }

    // Save Calories Field
    if( isset( $_POST['_сalories'] ) ) {
        $product->update_meta_data( '_сalories', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['_сalories'] ) );
    }

    // Save Ingredients Field
    if( isset( $_POST['_ingredients'] ) ) {
        $product->update_meta_data( '_ingredients', sanitize_textarea_field( $_POST['_ingredients'] ) );
    }
}

// Display product custom fields values on single product pages under short description and on archive pages
add_action('woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_form', 'display_custom_meta_field_value', 25 );
add_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'display_custom_meta_field_value', 25 );
function display_custom_meta_field_value() {
    global $product;

    if( $custom_weight = $product->get_meta('_custom_weight') )
        echo  '<p id="value-on-single-product">' . __("Weight:", "woocommerce") . ' ' . $custom_weight . 'g' . '</p>';

    if( $сalories = $product->get_meta('_сalories') )
        echo  '<p id="value-on-single-product">' . __("Calories:", "woocommerce") . ' ' . $сalories . ' kcal.' . '</p>';

    if( $ingredients = $product->get_meta('_ingredients') )
        echo '<p id="value-on-single-product">' . __("Ingredients:", "woocommerce") . ' ' . $ingredients . '</p>';
}

// Add custom fields values under cart item name in cart
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', 'custom_cart_item_name', 10, 3 );
function custom_cart_item_name( $item_name, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) {
    if( ! is_cart() )
        return $item_name;

    if( $value1 = $cart_item['data']->get_meta('_custom_weight') ) {
        $item_name .= '<br><span class="custom-field"><strong>' . __("Weight", "woocommerce") . ':</strong> ' . $value1 . 'g</span>';
    }

    if( $value2 = $cart_item['data']->get_meta('_сalories') ) {
        $item_name .= '<br><span class="custom-field"><strong>' . __("Calories", "woocommerce") . ':</strong> ' . $value2 . 'kcal</span>';
    }

    if( $value3 = $cart_item['data']->get_meta('_ingredients') ) {
        $item_name .= '<br><span class="custom-field"><strong>' . __("Ingredients", "woocommerce") . ':</strong> <br>' . $value3 . '</span>';
    }

    return $item_name;
}

// Display custom fields values under item name in checkout
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_cart_item_quantity', 'custom_checkout_cart_item_name', 10, 3 );
function custom_checkout_cart_item_name( $item_qty, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) {
    if( $value1 = $cart_item['data']->get_meta('_custom_weight') ) {
        $item_qty .= '<br><span class="custom-field"><strong>' . __("Weight", "woocommerce") . ':</strong> ' . $value1 . 'g</span>';
    }

    if( $value2 = $cart_item['data']->get_meta('_сalories') ) {
        $item_qty .= '<br><span class="custom-field"><strong>' . __("Calories", "woocommerce") . ':</strong> ' . $value2 . 'kcal</span>';
    }

    if( $value3 = $cart_item['data']->get_meta('_ingredients') ) {
        $item_qty .= '<br><span class="custom-field"><strong>' . __("Ingredients", "woocommerce") . ':</strong> <br>' . $value3 . '</span>';
    }

    return $item_qty;
}

// Display custom fields values on orders and email notifications
add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_item_name', 'custom_order_item_name', 10, 2 );
function custom_order_item_name( $item_name, $item ) {
    $product = $item->get_product();

    if( $value1 = $product->get_meta('_custom_weight') ) {
        $item_name .= '<br><span class="custom-field"><strong>' . __("Weight", "woocommerce") . ':</strong> ' . $value1 . 'g</span>';
    }

    if( $value2 = $product->get_meta('_сalories') ) {
        $item_name .= '<br><span class="custom-field"><strong>' . __("Calories", "woocommerce") . ':</strong> ' . $value2 . 'kcal</span>';
    }

    if( $value3 = $product->get_meta('_ingredients') ) {
        $item_name .= '<br><span class="custom-field"><strong>' . __("Ingredients", "woocommerce") . ':</strong> <br>' . $value3 . '</span>';
    }

    return $item_name;
}
```

Code goes on function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

---

**On cart page:**

[image]

**On checkout page:**

[image]

**On order received page:**

[image]

**On email notifications:**

[image]