# Save and display product selected custom data in WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I use the code, that on the product editing page shows the checkbox "Roast Level". When the manager clicks on this checkbox, a select box appears on the page of a single product, allowing the customer to select "Roast Level".

When selecting and adding a product to the cart, the selected value appears in the cart itself. This value is also shown on the checkout page, on the "Thank You" page, in the order, on the email notification, and on the order editing page in the admin panel.

Here is the code:

```
// Display Checkbox Field
add_action('woocommerce_product_options_general_product_data', 'roast_custom_field_add');

function roast_custom_field_add() {
    global $post;

    // Checkbox
    woocommerce_wp_checkbox(
            array(
                    'id' => '_roast_checkbox',
                    'label' => __('Roast Level', 'woocommerce'),
                    'description' => __('Enable roast level!', 'woocommerce')
            )
    );
}

// Save Checkbox Field
add_action('woocommerce_process_product_meta', 'roast_custom_field_save');

function roast_custom_field_save($post_id) {
    // Custom Product Checkbox Field
    $roast_checkbox = isset($_POST['_roast_checkbox']) ? 'yes' : 'no';
    update_post_meta($post_id, '_roast_checkbox', esc_attr($roast_checkbox));
}

// Display Select Box
add_action('woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button', 'add_roast_custom_field', 0);

function add_roast_custom_field() {
    global $product;

    // If is single product page and have the "roast_checkbox" enabled we display the field
    if (is_product() && $product->get_meta('_roast_checkbox') === 'yes') {

            echo '<div>';

            woocommerce_form_field('roast_custom_options', array(
                    'type' => 'select',
                    'class' => array('my-field-class form-row-wide'),
                    'label' => __('Roast Level'),
                    'required' => false,
                    'options' => array(
                            '' => 'Please select',
                            'Blue' => 'Blue',
                            'Rare' => 'Rare',
                            'Medium Rare' => 'Medium Rare',
                            'Medium' => 'Medium',
                            'Medium Well' => 'Medium Well',
                            'Well Done' => 'Well Done'
                    )
            ), '');

            echo '</div>';
    }
}

// Add as custom cart item data
add_filter('woocommerce_add_cart_item_data', 'add_custom_cart_item_data', 10, 3);

function add_custom_cart_item_data($cart_item_data, $product_id, $variation_id) {
    if (isset($_POST['roast_custom_options'])) {
            $cart_item_data['roast_option'] = wc_clean($_POST['roast_custom_options']);
    }
    return $cart_item_data;
}

// Add custom fields values under cart item name in cart
add_filter('woocommerce_cart_item_name', 'roast_custom_field', 10, 3);

function roast_custom_field($item_name, $cart_item, $cart_item_key) {
    if (!is_cart())
            return $item_name;

    if (isset($cart_item['roast_option'])) {
            $item_name. = '<br /><div class="my-custom-class"><strong>'.__("Roast Level", "woocommerce").
            ':</strong> '.$cart_item['roast_option'].
            '</div>';
    }
    return $item_name;
}

// Display roast custom fields values under item name in checkout
add_filter('woocommerce_checkout_cart_item_quantity', 'roast_custom_checkout_cart_item_name', 10, 3);

function roast_custom_checkout_cart_item_name($item_qty, $cart_item, $cart_item_key) {
    if (isset($cart_item['roast_option'])) {
            $item_qty. = '<br /><div class="my-custom-class"><strong>'.__("Roast Level", "woocommerce").
            ':</strong> '.$cart_item['roast_option'].
            '</div>';
    }
    return $item_qty;
}


// Save chosen slelect field value to each order item as custom meta data and display it everywhere
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_create_order_line_item', 'save_order_item_product_fitting_color', 10, 4);

function save_order_item_product_fitting_color($item, $cart_item_key, $values, $order) {
    if (isset($values['_roast_option'])) {
            $key = __('Roast Level', 'woocommerce');
            $value = $values['_roast_option'];
            $item->update_meta_data($key, $value);
    }
}
```

This code works well in the Storefront theme, but for some reason, it does not work in the theme I bought on Themeforest. Developers can not help, they say that I need to contact the person who wrote this code. And that's why...

I also use code that works in the Storefront and in the purchased theme. Here it is - [Show custom fields on the order editing page in WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56259910/show-custom-fields-on-the-order-editing-page-in-woocommerce)
, those. It works great in these two themes.

As I understand it, this is due to the syntax "echo". In the form of "Roast Level" this syntax is, therefore the form is shown. When displaying selected data in the cart or on the checkout page, this syntax is not.

---

**UPDATE**

Here is the code that doesn't work without "echo":

```
// Add custom fields values under cart item name in cart
add_filter('woocommerce_cart_item_name', 'roast_custom_field', 10, 3);

function roast_custom_field($item_name, $cart_item, $cart_item_key) {
    if (!is_cart())
            return $item_name;

    if (isset($cart_item['roast_option'])) {
            $item_name. = '<br /><div class="my-custom-class"><strong>'.__("Roast Level", "woocommerce").
        ':</strong> '.$cart_item['roast_option'].
        '</div>';
    }
    return $item_name;
}

// Display roast custom fields values under item name in checkout
add_filter('woocommerce_checkout_cart_item_quantity', 'roast_custom_checkout_cart_item_name', 10, 3);

function roast_custom_checkout_cart_item_name($item_qty, $cart_item, $cart_item_key) {
    if (isset($cart_item['roast_option'])) {
            $item_qty. = '<br /><div class="my-custom-class"><strong>'.__("Roast Level", "woocommerce").
        ':</strong> '.$cart_item['roast_option'].
        '</div>';
    }
    return $item_qty;
}


// Save chosen slelect field value to each order item as custom meta data and display it everywhere
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_create_order_line_item', 'save_order_item_product_fitting_color', 10, 4);

function save_order_item_product_fitting_color($item, $cart_item_key, $values, $order) {
    if (isset($values['_roast_option'])) {
            $key = __('Roast Level', 'woocommerce');
            $value = $values['_roast_option'];
            $item->update_meta_data($key, $value);
    }
}
```

I ask to change my code so that it has the syntax "echo", so that the selected data is output using "echo". I will be glad for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Following Code should Work**

```
/*---------------------------------------------------------------
*Display Select Box
---------------------------------------------------------------*/
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button', 'add_roast_custom_field', 0 );
function add_roast_custom_field() {
    global $product;

    // If is single product page and have the "roast_checkbox" enabled we display the field
    if ( is_product() && $product->get_meta( '_roast_checkbox' ) === 'yes' ) {

        echo '<div class="roast_select">';

        $select = woocommerce_form_field( 'roast_custom_options', array(
            'type'          => 'select',
            'class'         => array('my-field-class form-row-wide'),
            'label'         => __('Roast Level'),
            'required'      => false,
            'return'       => false,
            'options'   => array(
                ''      => 'Please select',
                'Blue'  => 'Blue',
                'Rare'  => 'Rare',
                'Medium Rare'   => 'Medium Rare',
                'Medium'    => 'Medium',
                'Medium Well'   => 'Medium Well',
                'Well Done' => 'Well Done'
            )
        ), '' );
        echo $select;
        echo '</div>';
    }
}
/*---------------------------------------------------------------
* Add as custom cart item data
---------------------------------------------------------------*/
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_cart_item_data', 'add_custom_cart_item_data', 10, 21 );
function add_custom_cart_item_data($cart_item_data, $product_id, $variation_id ){

    if( isset( $_POST['roast_custom_options'] ) ) {
        $cart_item_data['roast_option'] = wc_clean( $_POST['roast_custom_options'] );
    }
    return $cart_item_data;
}
/*---------------------------------------------------------------
* Add custom fields values under cart item name in cart
---------------------------------------------------------------*/

add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', 'roast_custom_field', 10, 21 );
function roast_custom_field( $item_name, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) {
    if( ! is_cart() )
        return $item_name;

    if( isset($cart_item['roast_option']) ) {
        $item_name .= '<br /><div class="my-custom-class"><strong>' . __("Roast Level", "woocommerce") . ':</strong> ' . $cart_item['roast_option'] . '</div>';
    }
    return $item_name;
}

/*---------------------------------------------------------------
* Display roast custom fields values under item name in checkout
---------------------------------------------------------------*/

add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_cart_item_quantity', 'roast_custom_checkout_cart_item_name', 10, 21 );
function roast_custom_checkout_cart_item_name( $item_qty, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) {
    if( isset($cart_item['roast_option']) ) {
        $item_qty .= '<br /><div class="my-custom-class"><strong>' . __("Roast Level", "woocommerce") . ':</strong> ' . $cart_item['roast_option'] . 'гр.</div>';
    }
    return $item_qty;
}

/*---------------------------------------------------------------
* Save chosen slelect field value to each order item as custom meta data and display it everywhere
---------------------------------------------------------------*/
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_create_order_line_item', 'save_order_item_product_fitting_color', 10, 21 );
function save_order_item_product_fitting_color( $item, $cart_item_key, $values, $order ) {
    if( isset($values['roast_option']) ) {
        $key = __('Roast Level', 'woocommerce');
        $value = $values['roast_option'];
        $item->update_meta_data( $key, $value ,$item->get_id());
    }
}

/*--------------------------------------------------------------------
The following code played the important role in your theme

Your add to cart form takes the values when user clicks on add to cart button 
After it ajax runs and takes the values from the butoons custom attribute
like data-product_id, data-roast_custom_options So i have added it using jquery 
check the code and your site. All the codesprovided by me working now.

--------------------------------------------------------------------*/

add_action('wp_footer','add_footer_script');
function add_footer_script(){
    ?>
    <script>
       jQuery('#roast_custom_options').on('change',function(){
           var roast_level = jQuery(this).val();
           /*console.log(roast_level); */
           var button = jQuery(this).closest('form').find('.add_to_cart_button'); console.log(button); 
           jQuery(button).attr('data-roast_custom_options',roast_level);
        });

    </script>
    <?php
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I probably didn’t explain well. My code works, but only in the Storefront theme. In other themes, for some reason, he does not display the selected data, shows only the form "Roast Level" on the page of a single product.

As I understand it, this is due to the syntax "echo". In the form of "Roast Level" this syntax is, therefore the form is shown. When displaying selected data in the cart or on the checkout page, this syntax is not.

I ask to change my code so that it has the syntax "echo", so that the selected data is output using "echo".

Comment: I have updated the answer check if it works your code is having some errors i have solved them...so please check if it works

Comment: You should tell me which code is not working for you

Comment: check if it works, if this don't work let me know which them are you using ... your theme may be not allowing you to add the functions or the priorities can be the reason...

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work. And I use everything. All that is in the code, I need. There are two variants: 1. Set the output data using "echo". 2. Give each option in the selection field its own designation, for example, roast1, roast2, etc. Then output as in the example - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56259910/show-custom-fields-on-the-order-editing-page-in-woocommerce

Comment: are you using any catche plugin you should check it if you are updating the code in functions.php of your active theme after updating the code you should clear the catche and then check...

Comment: also the process involves of test is after you update code  then clear catche and then try adding the product in cart then check if selected roast comes in cart and check out page then once you place the order check if tha data i.e roast level is coming in order data you have to follow these steps each time you update and check if the code is working let me know if you are following all these steps, because the same code is working in storefront theme as well as in other themes i used

Comment: Everything works fine. Thank you very much! You saved my life)